# Get google analytics Api response

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to return `GA` API response but having a authentication error, which I don't know why. What I have done so far is right below.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
```

then `gapi` response method.

```
queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
        path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
        root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            reportRequests: [{
                viewId: "82708385",
                dateRanges: [{
                        startDate: '7daysAgo',
                        endDate: 'today'
                    }],
                metrics: [{
                        expression: 'ga:sessions'
                }]
            }]
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
},
```

But in the end it's catching an **AUTH** error. The thing is. I already create a `OAuth 2.0 Client ID` credentials in `console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?` and using that `client_id` in meta.

error is:

> "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential.
>   Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
>   authentication credential.

It's look like I am missing something here? How can I solve this issue.

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message.  **catching an AUTH error.** is not enough information on exactly which auth error you are getting.

Comment: @Tay, may be the access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

Comment: @VijayaVarmaLanke the client library should handle that by requesting authorization again.

Comment: @DaImTo I updated the question with error message

Comment: I would check your client id again go grab it again from the Google developer console. sounds like you have copied it incorrectly.  Make sure its the correct type as well.  Web application.

Comment: I am copying `client_id` directly from the console and I also created a credentials as `Other` and tried it's `client_id` too. but there is no difference still getting the error. @DaImTo

Comment: Theres the problem you are using JavaScript you need to create type web/browser other is for installed application.

Answer (score 0):

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

You appear to have set your client id.  The most next logical thing to consider would be wrong is that there is something wrong with your credentials.  Either your you copied the client id incorrectly or you created the wrong type.

I believe this is a setup issue with your client. If you check the tutorial [Hello analytics reporting java script.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

[image]

As you can see you need to create type Web Application. According to your comments you have created type other this will not work as that is used for installed applications.

Comment: thank you for the answer, in the comment, I meant this: I created Web App type. but I didn't get any result, so I just tried `Other` too... It doesn't mean that I didn't create Web App type...

Comment: Did you get no results or did you get an error that is two different things.  No results means there is no data for the request you made for the user you have authenticated with that doesn't mean that there is an issue with your code.  Type other will not work with JavaScript as it is not an installed programming language like C# or java you will not be running it on a computer.  It will be hosted on a web server run in a Browser this is why you need to use Web application type.